# git clone fail in gitlab runner docker

Tags: gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

No idea why the git clone fail for all the time, I have add the correct host key and private key, but it still fail. Someone said the gitlab pipeline not support pulling from http, so I changed to ssh, but still failed

```
$ echo "$SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS" > ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ chmod 600 ~/.ssh/known_hosts
$ echo -e "Host *\n\tStrictHostKeyChecking no\n\n" > ~/.ssh/config
$ id
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$ ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /mytest/private;git clone 
git@gitlab.home.kd:root/ansible-home.git --recursive -vvvvv'
Identity added: /mytest/private (/mytest/private)
Cloning into 'ansible-home'...
Warning: Permanently added 'gitlab.home.kd' (ECDSA) to the list of 
known hosts.
Server supports multi_ack_detailed
Server supports side-band-64k
Server supports ofs-delta
Server version is git/2.18.1
want e959694c7a5c95f27572ae6f2aa6e1aa6fa23a99 (HEAD)
want 989fd778545ca1ae507cad35ae224d8bb92f2db4 (refs/heads/dev)
want e959694c7a5c95f27572ae6f2aa6e1aa6fa23a99 (refs/heads/master)
done
$ ls /ansible-home
ls: cannot access '/ansible-home': No such file or directory
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```